# AngularJS: Accessing child elements in directive

Tags: angularjs, directive

I want to prettify my main HTML and want to use own directives to create a tab box.
I want to write the code for the tab box like this:

```
<my-tab-box>
  <my-tab label="Tab 1" active="true">Content 1</my-tab>
  <my-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</my-tab>
</my-tab-box>
```

Angular should translate the above code to something like:

```
<div class="tab-box">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">Tab 1</li>
    <li>Tab 2</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content">
    Content 1
  </div>
</div>
```

But I don't know how to access the child elements of `tab-box` from within the `tab-box` directive. I need this to get the child element that has the attribute `access="true"` and get the child's inner HTML to display it in the `<div class="content">` element.

How to realize that?
Am I working against the Angular philosophy?

Thanks! Malte

Comment: In your directive, can you add '$watch' to check if particular element is updated with access="true" attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can best see how that can work by looking at the implementation in angular-bootstrap:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js

Basically you can make the directives collaborate by having the parent directive injected into your child directive ( "require: 'MyTabBox'" in you MyTab controller).

You also need to understand transclusion.

That very same scenario is also explained in angular's developer guide:
See section "Creating Directives that Communicate" at 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive